# C++ OpenGL shading version error - GLSL x is not supported [Ubuntu 16.04]

Tags: c++, ubuntu, opengl, glsl, shader

I am currently working on a project using OpenGL on Ubuntu 16.04 and have run into a major issue. At this point I have no idea what to do as it feels like I have tried everything in order to fix this.

For some reason my shader just won't compile and returns the following error:

```
Failed to compile vertex shader!
0:1(10): error: GLSL 4.50 is not supported. Supported versions are: 1.10, 1.20, 1.30, 1.00 ES, 3.00 ES, 3.10 ES, and 3.20 ES`
```

I have adjusted the version in the shader file without any luck. `#version  450 core` etc. but I keep getting the same result.

For reference, here is the output of `sudo glxinfo | grep "OpenGL"`:

```
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 520 (Skylake GT2)
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 13.1.0-devel
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.50
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 13.1.0-devel
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 13.1.0-devel
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

The output from glxinfo shows OpenGL core 4.5 is installed, so why is this not supported?

I have also tried to find the current version of OpenGL used in the project: `std::cout << "OpenGL version: " << glGetString(GL_VERSION) << std::endl;` which results in a blank return.

I have spent 10 hours on this single issue until now, so any help is appreciated!

Edit:
Is there a way to force the project/Ubuntu to use OpenGL and not GLSL by i.e. removing GLSL completely (this part)?

```
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 13.1.0-devel
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

Comment: According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL_Shading_Language#Versions) table it seems I have two different versions of OpenGL installed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For anyone else experiencing the same issues, this was the solution that worked for me:

```
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 0);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
```

Comment: Glad you solved  your problem, as a suggestion for next time: either post the complete code or add some more details (no idea you were using glfw)

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Ill make sure to do so.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like you're not explicitly asking for a *core profile* context. Your glxinfo output shows, that *compatibility profile* contexts (there were no "compatibility" profiles before OpenGL-3.0, but that's a moot point for this) are not supported:

This is telling you that in *core profile* up to v4.5 is supported:

```
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 13.1.0-devel
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.50
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
```

… and this does tell you, that the highest version that's not explicitly marked *core* is going to be OpenGL-3.0:

```
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 13.1.0-devel
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
```

So either request a *core* profile or accept that you're stuck to GL-3.0 and below.

---

Just for comparison, here's how it looks for an OpenGL implementation (NVidia) that does support OpenGL-4.x even outside a core profile:

```
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.4.0 NVIDIA 367.27
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.40 NVIDIA via Cg compiler
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL version string: 4.5.0 NVIDIA 367.27
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.50 NVIDIA
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. 

I have defined `#version 450 core` in my shader files, I am still getting the same result if this is what you meant.

Comment: @NicolaiPrebensen: This is not what I meant: I meant that when creating the OpenGL context you have to request a core profile context. You didn't tell us, how you're creating the OpenGL context (which libraries/framework you use). Is it GLUT, GLFW, SLMF, SDL, GTK, Qt plain Xlib/GLX? If you tell us how you do it, we can tell you how to make it choose a core profile context.

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to use 4.5 capabilities you need a core profile and that is supported on your system according to this output line

```
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 13.1.0-devel
```

The other output line

```
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 13.1.0-devel
```

does not mean that you have two different openGL drivers but that you can afford OpenGL 3.0 tops without core profile.

In order to use the core profile capabilities make sure to enable it as well as compiling your shaders with the correct preprocessor directive

```
// Example using glut for context initialization
glutInitContextVersion(4, 5);
glutInitContextProfile(GLUT_CORE_PROFILE);
glutInit(&argc, argv);

// Shaders
#version 450
...
```

Comment: Hmm. It seems like I am missing some libraries as I cannot find these functions.

Comment: @NicolaiPrebensen The code to create and bind context is platform specific, take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/879128/1938163)

Comment: @NicolaiPrebensen I suppose you could also try to do this with bare X11/Xlib as in [this example by datenwolf](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17608618/1938163) although I've never tried it myself

Comment: Ill give this a shot. Just have to read up a little bit on how to use those libraries.

Comment: @NicolaiPrebensen Fwiw here's a repo which does some simple image processing with openGL core profile and compute shaders, it uses GLUT: https://github.com/marcodiiga/glquad

Comment: Thank you so much for the help Macro. This led me in the right direction. I will add a new reply with my working solution!

Comment: @NicolaiPrebensen Glad to hear you solved your problem and other thanks for posting here your solution: it might help other people as well!

Answer (score -1):

Try next code in your shader:

"#version 320 es

precision mediump float;

...your code "

Comment: This answer would be better if you added a little explanation about why this will help.

Answer (score -2):

GLSL is the shader language used by OpenGL although the two version numbers don't always match. From your ourput,  it looks like you are using the on Chip Intel GPU. The driver for this chip qorks through Mesa which as far as I know does not support OpenGL 4 yet.

If you have a Nvidia card, you can install the proprietary NVidia driver which does support the latest version of OpenGL. Otherwise you will need to modify your shaders to use an older version of the language.

Comment: Thank you for the response.

I do not have a Nvidia card as this is my laptop with integrated Intel graphics (i7 Core / Skylake) - Which also is the newest release from Intel as far as I know. From the looks of it, it seems like it supports OpenGL 4 as it has the string `OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 13.1.0-devel` but I am not sure to be honest.